# How RSS syndication works?

Tags: xml, rss, syndication

I have created rss.xml file and placed it in the root folder of my site. As of now I am using Google reader to check if I am getting appropriate updates or not.
The problem is I am not getting updates. But when I unsubscribe and again subscribe I get the updates.
Am I missing something? Heard about RSS syndication but didn't found any help on that. Also I have registered my feed on syndic8.com but still !!!.
Any help is appreciated.

I keep on updating my rss.xml file with new contents. And I waited for 3 days and I did not any update. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your RSS, both before and after an update? You need to check that a new `item` is definitely added, that it has a `guid` that Google hasn't seen before, that the `pubDate` is correctly set, and a few other things. It's also always worth running your RSS through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/) to make sure your feed is valid.

Comment: Finally, it had worked. I just created a sitemap and submitted it to Google. Do not understand but this solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will periodically poll the server to see if the RSS feed has changed. Most clients default to hourly, RSS feeds can specify other periods which some clients will honour.

I'd guess that you just aren't being patient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the Time To Live in your feed. [Understanding TTL](http://www.therssweblog.com/?guid=20070529130637).

From the article: "One of the most misunderstood element in RSS is the `<ttl>`. It stands for Time To Live and it controls how often a feed should be refreshed"